# validate fields that might not be there

Tags: php, javascript, html

I've got a form with inputfield that i generated like this

```
if (strpos($text, "[Objekt]") !== false) {
?>
<input type = "text" name = "objekt" value = "" /><br/>
<?php
}
```

now i want try to validate this with javascript but as soon
as the js hits a field that is not there it stops working
is there a solution to bypass this

this is my js

```
            function isNumber(n) {
            return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
        }
        function validate() {
                if ((!isNumber(document.form1.test.value)) ||
                        (!isNumber(document.form1.bezahlt.value)) ||
                        (!isNumber(document.form1.differenz.value)) ||
                        (!isNumber(document.form1.saeumzuschlag.value)) ||
                        (!isNumber(document.form1.mahngebuehr.value)) ||
                        (!isNumber(document.form1.gesamtsumme.value))) {
                    alert("error");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
        }
```

Comment: try { } catch(e){} statements

Comment: By checking if the field exists

Comment: Please show your JavaScript code, that's the part that you're having trouble with.

Comment: You could also just make the field hidden and disabled if you don't want to show it to user yet keep the validator from crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to reference `document.form1.objekt` and it doesn't exist you'll get `undefined`, and trying to reference `undefined.value` will give you an error. You can test if the field exists with:

```
 if (document.form1.objekt) {
     // exists, so do something with document.form1.objekt.value
 }
```

There are several ways you could plug an undefined test into your existing validation code, e.g.:

```
if (!(document.form1.objekt==undefined || isNumber(document.form1.objekt.value))) { ...
```

In context:

```
function validate() {
    if (!(document.form1.objekt==undefined || isNumber(document.form1.objekt.value)) ||
            (!isNumber(document.form1.test.value)) ||
            (!isNumber(document.form1.bezahlt.value)) ||
            (!isNumber(document.form1.differenz.value)) ||
            (!isNumber(document.form1.saeumzuschlag.value)) ||
            (!isNumber(document.form1.mahngebuehr.value)) ||
            (!isNumber(document.form1.gesamtsumme.value))) {
        alert("error");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Obviously you can apply a similar test to the other fields if needed.

Alternatively you could add a `class="numeric"` to all of the inputs that need that particular validation, and then in your JS select all inputs with that class and pass them to `isNumber()` in a loop. Then it wouldn't matter which specific fields are in included in the page.

**UPDATE:** To implement my last suggestion make sure all the numeric fields have `class="numeric"` and then do something like this:

```
function validate() {
    var numFields = document.querySelectorAll("input.numeric");
    for (var i=0; i < numFields.length; i++) {
        if (!isNumber(numFields[i].value)){
            alert(numFields[i].name + " is invalid");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you need to support old versions of IE (older than v8) you won't be able to use `.querySelectorAll()`, you'll need to do something else - e.g., use `document.getElementsByTagName("input")` and then test the class of each one within the loop.

Comment: could u make an example for the last part?

Comment: I like this solution. Checking for `undefined` is a lot cleaner than using a bunch of try/catch blocks, IMO.

Comment: Thanks @Dan. Yes, try/catch is messy. I would only use try/catch if an external library (or my own code) was throwing custom exceptions, or (not really in JS, but in other languages) to handle I/O exceptions or that sort of thing. Hard-coding the individual fields for validation is messy too, but it's easy enough to validate in a loop without the code needing to know about the individual fields.

Answer (score 2):

Use a try-catch statement like this:

```
try {
//your code
} catch(e) {
//if it gets here your code had a problem (the input does not exist)
}
```